# How to prevent duplicates in my listview? Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, duplicates, mapping

So I've been trying to figure out for hours how to stop adding duplicates to my ListView, nothing is working. Please help. I keep getting duplicate places in my listview when I map my events list to the place list tile.

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 8.0),
            controller: _scrollController,
            shrinkWrap: true,

                children: PlaceMapState.events
                .map((place) => _PlaceListTile(
                      place: place,
                      // onPlaceChanged: (value) => _onPlaceChanged(value),
                    ))
                .toSet().toList(),
          ),
        ),
    ],

    );

  }

}
```

This is where I retrieve data and place it in events list:

```
 void initPlace(request,requestId){
     var placeId = requestId;
   MarkerId placeIdVal = new MarkerId(placeId);
    //creating new Place
    final Place place = new Place(id: placeIdVal.toString(),

        latLng: LatLng(request['latLng'].latitude, request['latLng'].longitude),
        name: request['title'],
        category: AppState.of(context).selectedCategory,
      );

    setState((){
      events.add(place);
      events.toSet();
    places[placeIdVal]=place;
    print(place);
    });


  }
```

Comment: PlaceMapState.events might contains duplicate records

Comment: any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: where you are assigning that value ?

Comment: I've edited the code and shown it

Answer (score 0):

```
   @override
   bool operator == (other) {
    return this.id == other.id;
   }
```

and

```
   if (!events.contains(place)) {
     events.add(place);
    }
```

Comment: where do i add this exactly?

Comment: within the setState

Answer (score 0):

override == operator in `Place` object

```
@override
  bool operator ==( other) {
  return  this.id==other.id;
  }
```

and check the item already present in the list before adding

```
if (!events.contains(place)) {
 events.add(place);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.toSet().toList()` is no working because is internally checking/matching for object references, so you need to override the == operator as @Nidheesh stated in order to matching by object's variable differences. Don't forget to add the fields (primitives and classes).

```
 class Place {
  final String name;
   final int id;

   Place({this.name, this.id});

   @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is Place &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    name == other.name &&
    id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode & id.hashCode;

}
```

For faster implementation, you can try Equatable library: https://pub.dev/packages/equatable